# Pros and Cons of XCODE4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Xcode4 just comes to us, developers like me would wonder know more user experiences about it

So post question here to seek pros and cons of xcode4.

Pros

> - support git
> - one window
> - unit test integrated ( how about this feature ? )

Cons

> - different GUI & shortcuts against 3.x

What else ?

Other questions:

> - any support for UML class diagram etc ?
> - how to navigate source codes more easily ?

Comment: You've nailed it I guess... FWIW I prefer XCode 4's unified UI to XCode 3.x's way.

Comment: I guess that xcode4 will replace xcode3.x , so that will be okay if no

Comment: con: skyrocketing blood pressure because of the crash that occurs at least every 2 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con's

- Massive download file!
- It's no longer free (still not much to pay, this would be a point if it was upwards of £/$50
- less third party support / tutorials for beginners.
- Something new to learn

Pro's

- Single window - trying to find all the windows can become a nightmare in v3
- New debugger
- auto fixes common errors in code - displays errors straight away
- navigators and jump bar make finding things easier.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is free for registered devs.

Comment: Thats true, its also free to register, It is on the app store listed as a paid app.

Comment: I don't think Xcode4 is available for the free developer accounts, just the paid ones.

Comment: Still the point is that it only costs about $2

Answer (score 1):

Pros:

- Everything is in one window.
- Auto complete is much better than 3.x version.
- Git support, and the way file versions are displayed.

Cons:

- It looks bit messy on my 13in MBP, I need to buy bigger display.
- Shortcut-key are not same for common operations what they used be in 3.x version

Answer (score 0):

I using it only for 2 days and i like the function that it shows fails immeditely i do not have to run the code.The biggest con is i think that they try to give everything to same place so when you use the build in IB it is a bit mess.I liked the separate version.

so like i said I using it only for 2 days so...

hope it helps